# Could not lock table <name> currenty in use by user <username> on machine <name>

Tags: .net, ms-access, connection-string

I'm opening an Access DataBase with just the provider and data source in my connectionstring. I'm trying to drop a table while the database is already opened and used by another application which I cannot alter nor see it's code and I'm getting the exception I mention in the topic. Which attributes should I add in my connectionstring so I can do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table is locked. There is nothing you can do to your connection string to get around this. If it were that easy, what would be the point of the locking mechanism?

Comment: Right, I think the connection might be open with Mode = Share Deny Write by the other application because I can open the same database from another computer via lan but can't drop the table with my code. So the next question is: How do I know if a table is opened and used in a database?

Answer (score 0):

If you are responsible for maintaining the database, then one suggestion l would make is purchasing the [Access Workbench](http://www.vb123.com/workbench/index.htm).  One of the features is the ability to lock out new users getting into a database file, and also see whom is logged on (to ask them to log out).  So if you need exclusive access to the database to perform maintenance, this will help ensure everyone is out of the database.

There a number of other features which have both helped me and save me huge amounts of work previously.  Please note l am not employed by the company.  I am just a **very happy user** of the software.  Note that there are other products available that offer these features as well.